# Linters doesn't work in Visual Studo Code (VSC)

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have problems with the linting in my VSC. Here is my `settings.json` as user:

```
"python.pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python3",
"python.linting.lintOnSave": true,
"python.linting.pylintEnabled": true,
"python.linting.flake8Enabled": true,
"python.linting.pylintPath": "/home/romain/Pip/bin/pylint",
"python.linting.flake8Path": "/home/romain/Pip/bin/flake8",
```

Where :

```
➜ which flake8
/home/romain/Pip/bin/flake8
```

and :

```
➜ which pylint 
/home/romain/Pip/bin/pylint
```

I have no error with this configuration, even when I'm saving my file with thins like that :

```
def function
    return 0
```

There is no linting. Did i miss something ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are forgetting:

```
"python.linting.enabled": true
```

Regards.

Comment: It changes nothing. By default, "python.linting.enabled" is true, cf : [https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting]

Comment: I'm sorry, I can't reproduce your error. With the same configuration my vscode works perfectly with pylint and flake8. I'm using vscode 1.20.1, python 3.5.2, pylint 1.8.2 and flake8 3.5.0.